# Shell command retrieving output of curl not working

Tags: shell, kubernetes, curl, output, livenessprobe

I am trying to execute this command through a Kubernetes livenessProbe, and I don't think it's working as expected as I see that the probe has failed in the pod events log.
This is the command:

```
sh -c reply=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://127.0.0.1:8080/login); if [ "$reply" -lt 200 -o "$reply" -ge 400 ]; then exit 1; fi;
```

When I exec into the container and run this command, I get this error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: [: Illegal number:
```

I echo $reply and nothing is stored in the reply variable after running the above command.
When I run the command without the 'sh -c' part, it works and the variable reply is getting populated. Somehow, the sh command is not able to read the output of the curl command...I tried to remove the -o /dev/null part of the curl request and that does not help.

How can I get this command to execute?

Comment: You set the variable `reply` inside the shell process (`sh -c `), but of course it isn't defined in the parent process, which executes the `if`. Aside from this: I think it is easier for maintenance and debugging, if you run a script file here, instead of stuffing the commands explicitly on the command line (i.e. doing a `sh -c /..../myscript.sh`).

Answer (score 0):

To run `sh -c`  with multiple synchronous commands, you need to enclose them inside quotes (either `"` or `'`) and add backslash before any similar quotes using inside the command and before the dollar sign `$` of the variable

```
sh -c "export reply=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://127.0.0.1:8080/login); if [ \"\$reply\" -lt 200 -o \"\$reply\" -ge 400 ]; then exit 1; fi;"
```

Comment: thanks for the response. it's still not working when i run your command inside the pod:
# sh -c "export reply=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://127.0.0.1:8080//login); if [ \"\$reply\" -lt 200 -o \"\$reply\" -ge 400 ]; then exit 1; fi;"
# echo $reply

#

Comment: Does it still returns the same error message?

Comment: hm no it doesn't, which is progress - but how come the $reply variable isn't populated?

Comment: Oh I think it's because the variable `$reply` scope is only within the commands string of `sh -c` so running `echo $reply` after `sh -c` is executed doesn't return the assigned value

Comment: Maybe you can add additional echo within the `if` statement for verification to be something like `if [ \"\$reply\" -lt 200 -o \"\$reply\" -ge 400 ]; then echo 1; else echo 2; fi; echo \"\$reply\";` to see if it checks and assigns the right value

Comment: Ah got it. yea that worked:
# sh -c "export reply=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://127.0.0.1:8080/ipp-blossom-dev-test-startup-probe/login); echo \$reply; if [ \"\$reply\" -lt 200 -o \"\$reply\" -ge 400 ]; then exit 1; fi;"
200

will have to play around with this command in the kubernetes deployment spec, right now the startup probe that's executing this command is still failing but maybe I made a typo - will check tomorrow. thank you for your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

Along with @tax evader's answer, I got the probe to work by putting this in the deployment spec:

```
livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command: ["sh", "-c", 'export reply=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://127.0.0.1:8080/login); if [ \"\$reply\" -lt 200 -o \"\$reply\" -ge 400 ]; then exit 1; fi;'
```

Comment: You don't need the `export`. You're using the variable only directly in the shell process, not in any child process.

Comment: Also, note that `test -a` and `test -o` are both deprecated. It's better form to write `if [ "$reply" -lt 200 ] || [ "$reply" -ge 400 ]`, two separate test statements; see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html, and notice the "OB" obsolescence markers.